# How to open an image file from bash in Mac?

Tags: command-line

I am fairly new with a Mac (Mac from work), and get more and more disappointed. Now I am blocked again, because I did not find an EASY way to open an image from the command line...

Here is how it works in Linux (simple, no installation required):

```
eog test.jpg
```

How to achieve the similar thing on a Mac?

Comment: open test.jpg or any executable e.g. install eog - however the issue is what do you want the command line to do after opening

Comment: Oh open works! I thought I tried this. Ok, problem solved. Thanks

Comment: If one of the answers below meets your needs, you should accept it.

Answer (score 44):

`open test.jpg` will open the image in the default application for JPEG files (on most Macs this will be Preview) and `open -a Pixelmator test.jpg` will open in the app `Pixelmator` if you have it installed. Obviously `Pixelmator` can be replaced with any application that can open the file.

The `open` command is quite powerful, it allows for opening files, directories and even URLs. I suggest you read the `man` page.

Comment: `open -a Photos test.jpg` will import the image `test.jpg` into `Photos` which is a lovely shortcut to know...

Comment: Running with wildcard in dir of interest - e.g., `open *.jpg` - opened Preview (default app in my case) with matches tiled in sidepane. Very convenient.

Answer (score 14):

If you only want to preview the file, I recommend to use Quicklook.

`qlmanage -p filename.jpg`

This will launch a Quick Look window with whatever file is specified as ‘filename.jpg’, the file type can be anything that Quick Look is compatible with (which seems to be just about everything).

Source: [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2007/12/24/use-quick-look-from-the-command-line/)